# How I can store data code for LONG time 100-200y - ESP32, Arduino, Data Retention, Reliability, Lifetime, Flash

Tags: esp32, memory, flash

I'm working on a research project in winch we want embedded sensors and logic, an ESP32, inside building's pillar surrounded by concrete. The ESP32 collects data through sensors, process them and send it to a sink using Bluetooth.

**Conditions:**

- The device then can be never removed or replaced once is deployed (is
  in the concrete pillar)
- The device is externally powered by a electrical source (cables) then
  power is not a constraint.
- The data communication between sensors are made using Bluetooth. We
  have tested that we can transmit data from inside concrete to an
  external sink that could be a phone.
- The device do not needs to store (write on memory) datas, the devices
  just reads process and sends environmental datas. The device can use
  READ ONLY MEMORY ROM to store the code no data store is needed.

Since the device CANNOT be removed my concern is to provide to the project a LONG LIFE EXPECTANCY (more then 100-200 years), in particular I'm concerned about the fact that the data in Flash Memory could disappear after few years (10y) due to limited Lifetime of flash memory in particular at relatively high temperature. If the data will disappear even the code stored in the flash disappear too and the sensor will fail to achieve its job.

**Question(s)**

- There are kinds of memories (flash on not flash), even ROM (read only
  memory) that are suitable to store code/data (information) for LONG
  (100-200years) time without fail with a size of 4MB or more?
- If yes where I can find them, I mean where I can buy? Which producer
  etc.?
- How I can integrate these memories in the ESP32? Can I replace them
  to replace the flash? Is it possible to do that?
- How I can program such memories? I mean how can I "flash" these kind
  of memory?

I thought that I can use a PROM: form Wikipedia, "A typical PROM comes with all bits reading as "1". Burning a fuse bit during programming causes the bit to be read as "0" by "blowing" the fuses, which is an irreversible process." but I can't figure out where I can start.

Comment: Why does the entire device (including its MANY single points of failure that will inevitably fail in 100 years) need to be embedded in the material? Why not embed the required sensors, with multiple reduncancy, and connect the "intelligence" to the outside where it can be updated and serviced? Also, do you think devices that can connect to Bluetooth will be around for another 100 years? What will the device be measuring and what manufacturer supports 100 years of service from their sensors?

Comment: I can see why you asked here. Arduino is, of course, the pinnacle of reliability, consistency, and good practice. =)

Comment: Cross posted with discussion here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-i-can-store-data-code-for-long-time-100-200y-data-retention-reliability-lifetime-flash/1177978

Comment: I think the people at Electronics Stack Exchange will be better suited to answer this, so I'll migrate it there.

Comment: You probably won't be able to find a fuse-link or other type of one time programmable (OTP) device that has the storage capacity you need.

Comment: Since the failure mechanism you seem to be worried about is charge bleed off (which is accelerated by high temperatures), could you do something like re-write the program at some periodic rate (once a year)?

Comment: You can get "M-Disc" CD-Rs that claim to have a predicted lifespan of 1000 years, though I have my doubts about the truth of that. Reading from them would require a more complex setup than a simple microcontroller, though, and you'd probably need to periodically replace the disc drive.